# splash screen doesn't load on real device - android 12 flutter

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

I'm stuck on this issue for one week now. I'm creating a flutter application, everything works perfectly on ios and android versions below 12.
Whenever I try to run apk on real android device, version 12, the splash screen never shows. I followed different tutorials, I tried the flutter native splash as below:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_lints: 2.0.1
  flutter_native_splash: 2.2.3

flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#2d2d75"

  android_12:

    image: assets/splash12.png
```

unfortunately, this didn't show the splash screen on android 12 .. I don't know what should I do to fix this.
I've seen some tricks to show it by closing app and re-open it but this didn't work too.

Comment: When you run your app from IDE in android 12 splash screen do not show. If you launch your app from launcher it'll show.

Comment: what do you mean by "from launcher" ? I generated apk and downloaded it on a real Android device, close app and re-open it but it did show too.

Answer (score 0):

i don't have experience with flutter but i wonder if this below code works:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
```

getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getSupportActionBar().hide();

```
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(splash.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        },3000);
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't think this could relate to the issue. I'm using flutter, which uses dart programming language. And I'm using flutter_native_splash package to generate the splash screen for both iOS and android.